# how can i print id and sub_id in nested table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i am printing nested table in rails. now i want to print their id as 1,2,3 and so on and nested content sub_id as 1.1,1.2...3.1 and so on. how can i do that  in rails?

```
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="300">Task Name</th>
        <th width="40">Planned start date</th>
        <th width="40">Planned end date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @stages.each do |stage| %>
        <tr class="stage">
          <td><%= stage.stage %></td>
          <td><%= stage.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
          <td><%= stage.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
        </tr>

        <% stage.tasks.each do |task| %>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><%= task.task_name %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
            <td><%= task.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
          </tr>

          <% task.sub_tasks.each do |sub_task| %>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-right"><%= sub_task.sub_task_name %></td>
              <td><%= sub_task.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
              <td><%= sub_task.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

how can i add column to user and print 1 for task and 1.1,1.2... for sub_task. i can't take id from table because their is multiple user(profiling). i want to print id from front end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a task counter and a sub-task counter.

```
...
<% stage.tasks.each_with_index do |task, task_index| %>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><%= "#{task_index + 1} #{task.task_name}"%></td>
    <td><%= task.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= task.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
  </tr>

  <% task.sub_tasks.each_with_index do |sub_task, sub_task_index| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-right"><%= "#{task_index + 1}.#{sub_task_index + 1} #{sub_task.sub_task_name }"%></td>
      <td><%= sub_task.planned_start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
      <td><%= sub_task.planned_end_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Read more about [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)